# Help in Discrete Mathematics (sets and cartesian product)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Give examples of sets A,B,C such that | (A - B) * C | = 6 < |2^C|. Explain your answer.

I was able to do this much, if it helps. Please help. I tried but it says I don’t have enough reputation to post a picture.

What have I done? I let A = {1,5}, B = {3,4}, C = {2,6} 
A\B = {1,5} ==> | {1,5} * {2,6} | = 6 < |2^C| ==> | (1,2) (1,6) (5,2) (5,6) | = 6 < | 2^C |. I can’t go any further.

Comment: The value of $|(A-B) \times C|$ is equal to $|(A-B)| \times |C|$. In your example, this value is 4.

Comment: For future reference, please refrain from including phrases like "halp with so and so!" in your title. Not very informative.

Answer (score 1):

Your example does not work, as Aravind said in his comment.

I think , that by $|2^C|$ you mean $2^{|C|}$. If yes, here is an example:

Let $A=\{1,2\}, B= \emptyset$ and $C=\{1,2,3\}.$

Then

$$|(A-B) \times C|= |A| \cdot|C|=2 \cdot 3=6 < 8 = 2^{|C|}.$$

Comment: Some folks use $2^C$ to indicate the power set of C, or the set of mappings $\{0,1\}\to C$, so their notation might be appropriate for their context.